# Adding an item in listview to another listview (Both are fragments)

Tags: java, android, android-listview, arraylist, android-package-managers

In my android app, I have two fragments one with installed apps and one that is blank. Both are listviews. I have a plus sign next to each item in the installed app listview. I am trying to make it so that when the user clicks the plus button. The listview app item goes to the blank fragment.

[image]

[image]

What I am trying to do is use create a public string array in the activity which is holding the tabs and when I click on the plus button add the packagename to the array.

And then in the blank fragment I am trying to check if it is found in the string array using the index.

In my BlockActivity class with holds the actionbar tabs I made this:

```
public static List<String> blacklist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And here is my blank fragment condition to retrieve the app:

```
if(!b || !c ) {

                if (BlockActivity.blacklist.contains(pi.packageName))
                {
                    packageList1.add(pi);
                }


            }
```

Now I think I have to you will have to reference to the position of the item the button was clicked from listview. Doing this, I will probably have to reference a method from my adapter class, but I am not sure how to implement that and the method.

I am trying to follow something similar to this:

http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Here is my adapter class:

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.R;

import java.util.List;

public class ApkAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    List<PackageInfo> packageList;
    Activity context;
    PackageManager packageManager;
    boolean[] itemChecked;

    public ApkAdapter(Activity context, List<PackageInfo> packageList,
                      PackageManager packageManager) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.packageList = packageList;
        this.packageManager = packageManager;
        itemChecked = new boolean[packageList.size()];
    }



    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView apkName;
        ImageButton ck1;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return packageList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return packageList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_apps, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.appname);
            holder.ck1 = (ImageButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.plus1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
             //holder.ck1.setTag(packageList.get(position));

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        // ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);



        Drawable appIcon = packageManager
                .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);




        String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
                packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
        appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 75, 75);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
        holder.apkName.setText(appName);

        // I guess the onClickListener would go here??!?!? Not sure how to do it in this         case and reference it to the Fragment??






        return convertView;

    }




}
```

And here is my blank fragment:

```
package com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomList_Activity extends Fragment
        implements OnItemClickListener {




    PackageManager packageManager;
    ListView apkList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {




        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_installed, container, false);
        packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();


        /*To filter out System apps*/

        apkList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.applist);

        new LoadApplications(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).execute();


        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * Return whether the given PackageInfo represents a system package or not.
     * User-installed packages (Market or otherwise) should not be denoted as
     * system packages.
     *
     * @param pkgInfo
     * @return boolean
     */
    private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
        return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true
                : false;
    }

    private boolean isSystemPackage1(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
        return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) != 0) ? false
                : true;
    }



    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }


    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        List<PackageInfo> packageList1 = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();

        public LoadApplications(Context context){
            Context mContext = context;
        }




        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
                    .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);





            for(PackageInfo pi : packageList) {
                boolean b = isSystemPackage(pi);
                boolean c = isSystemPackage1(pi);

                if(!b || !c ) {

                    if (BlockActivity.blacklist.contains(pi.packageName))
                    {
                        packageList1.add(pi);
                    }


                }
            }

            //sort by application name

            final PackageItemInfo.DisplayNameComparator comparator = new PackageItemInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager);

            Collections.sort(packageList1, new Comparator<PackageInfo>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(PackageInfo lhs, PackageInfo rhs) {
                    return comparator.compare(lhs.applicationInfo, rhs.applicationInfo);
                }
            });


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit**: Here is the fragment with the installedapps

http://pastebin.com/L7dYfp3n

Comment: Can you include your fragment with the Installed apps?

Comment: Edit made @Shyamal Keshav

Comment: Just included it in a pastebin